# Flex 3: States : CreationPolicy = All

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i have a component with different states, when i assign some value in another state, i get a runtime error [null]

How can i load all the states at once? using creationpolicy or anyther way?

In  TabNavigator, creationpolicy=all solves that problem, but how to solve this issue when there are many states?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AddChild element has a creationPolicy property, which defaults to 'auto' but accepts 'all' or 'none' as well. Setting it to 'all' should work for you:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/states/AddChild.html#creationPolicy

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for flex 4.6 since you receive deprecation error message. Seems that the mxml compiler will not recognise any form of trying to force components in all states to be loaded.  One workaround to this, is to at creation time manually switch states to all those you are using such as: currentState = "Edit"; currentState = "Record"; currentState = "Default"; note that you can't even use a for each in loop with string constants, you have to use in-line string literals so that the mxml compiler will accept them.

Another solution which seems much neater is to initialize your component as follows:

ref: http://compacted.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/unit-testing-flex-states/#comments

```
public static function initializeStates(component:UIComponent):void {
  for each (var state:mx.states.State in component.states) {
    for each (var override:IOverride in state.overrides) {
      override.initialize();
    }
  }
}
```